# Robot Framework - did not match any elements even in the firepath

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I try to automate the CMS using robot framework, I got the XPath using firepath, I'm able to locate the element in Firefox, if I refresh the page, I couldn't locate the same XPath,I thought XPath got changed, but I got the same XPath when I try to get after page refresh,

IN SHORT again:
1) Got the Xpath, say "A"
2) Refresh the page
3) try to locate the element using "A".but it shows no element found
4) Get the new XPath, say "B"
5) Both A and B are same if I try now with A it works,
I need to automate this scenario, Thanks for your time.
I tried Frame too.

## Note:

Every time after refresh element gets hidden until the click operation takes place.

```
<document>
<html style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
<head>
**xpath**<body id="m_bodyElem" class="Gecko Gecko54 ENUS cms-bootstrap ui-layout-container" style="position: relative; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: medium none;">
<form id="aspnetForm" method="post" action="./CMSAdministration.aspx">
<div class="aspNetHidden">**xpath**
***
</document>
```

**AFTER DOM ACTIVATION**

```
<document>
<html>
<head>
<body id="m_bodyElem" class="Gecko Gecko54 ENUS cms-bootstrap">
<form id="aspnetForm" method="post" action="./UIPage.aspx?elementguid=a5568855-b030-47ff-801a-d524618a2ca7&displaytitle=false" onsubmit="if (window.Loader) { window.Loader.submitForm(1000, false); }; return true;">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm']; if (!theForm) { theForm = document.aspnetForm; } function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) { if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) { theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget; theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument; theForm.submit(); } } //]]> </script>
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZBvGXq_vBGigUCFpfznup-OhZmSOTsQXuUy4Gn5GLidTPeGZMHkjMcSO21b0MZpf4w2&t=636160552680000000" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ function CloseDialog(refreshPage) { // Check that the document content has not been changed without saving. Stop closing the dialog when user decides to save the content. if (window.CheckChanges && !CheckChanges()) { return false; } if (typeof(refreshPage) === "undefined") { refreshPage = true; } try { // IE9 fix - wopener doesn't have to be available if(refreshPage && window.wopener && window.wopener.RefreshWOpener) { wopener.RefreshWOpener(window); } } catch(err) {} var canClose = true; if (window.onCloseDialog) { canClose = window.onCloseDialog(); } if (canClose) { if(top.closeDialog && (top != window)) { setTimeout(function(){ if(top && top.closeDialog && (top != window)){ top.closeDialog(window) } }, 1); } else { top.close(); } } return false; } //]]> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ function GetTop(){ if(top.getTop) { return top.getTop(window); } else { return top; } } //]]> </script>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%2fCMSScripts%2fUI%2fUIPage.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ function ToggleDiv(label){ var div = $cmsj(label).parent(); var image = div.find('.ToggleImage'); var hiddenField = image.next(); var affectedElements = div.find('.editing-form-category-caption').next(); if(hiddenField.val() == 'True') { div.removeClass('Collapsed'); hiddenField.val('False') image.attr('src', '/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?image=%5bImages.zip%5d%2fCMSModules%2fCMS_PortalEngine%2fWebpartProperties%2fminus.png'); affectedElements.show(); } else { div.addClass('Collapsed'); hiddenField.val('True'); image.attr('src', '/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?image=%5bImages.zip%5d%2fCMSModules%2fCMS_PortalEngine%2fWebpartProperties%2fplus.png'); affectedElements.hide(); } } //]]> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ function modalDialog(url, name, width, height, otherParams, noWopener, forceModal, forceNewWindow, setTitle) { // Header and footer is greater than before, increase window size accordingly if (typeof(height) === "number") { height += 66; } // Set default parameter values if (setTitle == undefined) { setTitle = true; } if (forceModal == undefined) { forceModal = true; } if (otherParams == undefined) { otherParams = 'toolbar=no,directories=no,menubar=no,modal=yes,dependent=yes,resizable=yes'; } var advanced = false; try { advanced = window.top.AdvancedModalDialogs; } catch (err) { } if (advanced && !forceNewWindow) { window.top.advancedModal(url, name, width, height, otherParams, noWopener, forceModal, setTitle, this); } else { var dHeight = height; var dWidth = width; if (width.toString().indexOf('%') != -1) { dWidth = Math.round(screen.width * parseInt(width, 10) / 100); } if (height.toString().indexOf('%') != -1) { dHeight = Math.round(screen.height * parseInt(height, 10) / 100); } var oWindow = window.open(url, name, 'width=' + dWidth + ',height=' + dHeight + ',' + otherParams); if (oWindow) { oWindow.opener = this; oWindow.focus(); } } } //]]> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ var applicationUrl = '/'; var imagesUrl = '/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?image=%5bImages.zip%5d%2f'; var isRTL = false; //]]> </script>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%7e%2fCMSScripts%2fBootstrap%2fbootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%7e%2fCMSScripts%2fBootstrap%2fbootstrap.custom.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%7e%2fCMSScripts%2fControls%2fcontextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ menuSettings['cg0_motheractions'] = { activecss : 'unigrid-action-menuactive', inactivecss : '', activecssoffset : 0, button : 'Both', vertical : 'Bottom', offsetx : 0, offsety : 0, horizontal : 'Left', dynamic : false, mouseover : false, level : 0, rtl : false, up : false }; CM_Init('cg0_motheractions'); function ContextMenuAsyncCloser_cg0_motheractions(sender, args) { HideContextMenu('cg0_motheractions',true); } RegisterAsyncCloser(ContextMenuAsyncCloser_cg0_motheractions); //]]> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ function ContextExportObject(definition, backup) { var query = ''; if (backup) { query += '&backup=true'; } modalDialog(applicationUrl + 'CMSModules/ImportExport/Pages/ExportObject.aspx?objectType=' + escape(definition[0]) + '&objectId=' + definition[1] + query, 'ExportObject', 750, 230); } function ContextRestoreObject(definition, backup) { var query = '&ug=UG_m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem'; if (backup) { query += '&backup=true'; } modalDialog(applicationUrl + 'CMSModules/ImportExport/Pages/RestoreObject.aspx?objectType=' + escape(definition[0]) + '&objectId=' + definition[1] + query, 'RestoreObject', 750, 400); } function ContextCloneObject(definition) { modalDialog(applicationUrl + 'CMSModules/Objects/Dialogs/CloneObjectDialog.aspx?objectType=' + escape(definition[0]) + '&objectId=' + definition[1], 'CloneObject', 750, 470); } //]]> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ menuSettings['cg0_mActions'] = { activecss : 'unigrid-menu-panel', inactivecss : 'unigrid-menu-panel', activecssoffset : 0, button : 'Both', vertical : 'Bottom', offsetx : 0, offsety : 0, horizontal : 'Left', dynamic : false, mouseover : false, level : 0, rtl : false, up : false }; CM_Init('cg0_mActions'); function ContextMenuAsyncCloser_cg0_mActions(sender, args) { HideContextMenu('cg0_mActions',true); } RegisterAsyncCloser(ContextMenuAsyncCloser_cg0_mActions); //]]> </script>
<script src="/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?scriptfile=%7e%2fCMSScripts%2fjquery%2fjquery-dialog.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=x6wALODbMJK5e0eRC_p1LReXSSMeIyuHkoW0S0JbeJThyUVM1Ht4tiF1s3IQMCFhPQK_xpltR2WGldkDgz-jn22orun3s0371LlvE1PAZKjo6kObtvOl-fuKz6i7Aya00&t=7c776dc1" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=P5lTttoqSeZXoYRLQMIScL2FKbXixpOQbTl1EIUzR5PmuwyrWWddMW5IgYL1QiI9_cn_1H5B6OyKNQvmWuhRMgoFqxMQlu84DtMU2tQiSt_N7pheWxn0ZjjBaQY6SWz90&t=7c776dc1" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ var CMS = CMS || {}; CMS.Application = { "applicationName": "PIM", "imagesUrl": "/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?image=%5bImages.zip%5d%2f", "isDebuggingEnabled": false, "contexthelp": { "contextHelp": { "application": { "description": null, "helpTopics": [] }, "helpTopics": [] }, "suppressContextHelp": false }, "applicationUrl": "/", "isDialog": false, "isRTL": "false" }; //]]> </script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('m$manScript', 'aspnetForm', ['tm$c$plc$lt$ctl00$HeaderActions$headerElem$pnlUp','','tm$c$plc$lt$ctl01$ST_UI_Listing$gridElem$a$pnlUpdate','','tm$c$ctxM','','tm$pM$pMP','','tm$c$plc$lt$ctl01$MessagesPlaceholder$plcMess$pMP','','tm$c$plc$lt$ctl01$ST_UI_Listing$gridElem$plcMess$pMP',''], [], [], 90, 'm'); //]]> </script>
<div id="m_pnlBody" class="PageBody">
<div id="m_pM_pMP"/>
<div id="m_c_m"/>
<div id="m_c_ctxM">
<div id="UIHeader" class="UIHeader">
<div id="m_c_plc_lt_ctl00_HeaderActions_headerElem_pnlUp">
<div id="m_c_plc_lt_ctl00_HeaderActions_headerElem_pnlActions" class="header-actions-container">
<button id="m_c_plc_lt_ctl00_HeaderActions_headerElem_headerElem_HA_0" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="m$c$plc$lt$ctl00$HeaderActions$headerElem$headerElem_HA_0" value="New Product Type" onclick="window.open('/CMSModules/AdminControls/Pages/UIPage.aspx?elementguid=6e43429b-1086-4669-8130-9ee24ebb1d21&displaytitle=false','_self'); return false;__doPostBack('m$c$plc$lt$ctl00$HeaderActions$headerElem$headerElem_HA_0','')">New Product Type</button>
</div>
<div id="m_c_plc_lt_ctl00_HeaderActions_headerElem_pnlAdditionalControls" class="dont-check-changes "/>
</div>
<div id="m_c_plc_lt_ctl00_HeaderActions_HeaderActions_zone_PageTitle_pnlHeader" class="PageHeader SimpleHeader">
<div id="CMSHeaderDiv" class="CMSHeaderDiv"/>
<div id="CKToolbar" class="CKToolbar"/>
</div>
<div id="UIContent" class="UIContent scroll-area" style="height: auto; top: 56px; bottom: 0px;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ (function() {var fn = function() {$get("m_manScript_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();//]]> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ document.pageLoaded = true; //]]> </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ cmsrequire(['CMS/UniGrid'], function(module) { new module({ "id": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem", "uniqueId": "m$c$plc$lt$ctl01$ST_UI_Listing$gridElem", "hdnCmdNameId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_hidCmdName", "hdnCmdArgId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_hidCmdArg", "hdnSelHashId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_hidSelectionHash", "hdnSelId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_hidSelection", "gridId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_v", "resetSelection": false, "allowSorting": false }); }); //]]> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ cmsrequire(['CMS/AdvancedExport'], function(module) { new module({ "id": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_a", "uniqueId": "m$c$plc$lt$ctl01$ST_UI_Listing$gridElem$a", "unigridId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem", "hdnParamId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_a_hdnParameter", "btnFullPostbackUniqueId": "m$c$plc$lt$ctl01$ST_UI_Listing$gridElem$a$btnFullPostback", "chlColumnsId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_a_chlColumns", "hdnDefaultSelectionId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_a_hdnDefaultSelection", "revRecordsId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_a_revRecords", "cvColumnsId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_a_cvColumns", "mdlAdvancedExportId": "m_c_plc_lt_ctl01_ST_UI_Listing_gridElem_a_mdlAdvancedExport", "fixHeight": false, "alertMessage": null }); }); //]]> </script>
```

The button I need to interact is 
//button[@id='m_c_plc_lt_ctl00_HeaderActions_headerElem_headerElem_HA_0']

Comment: Can you please share HTML code for that element?

Comment: After you refresh, do you wait for the page to finish rendering before trying to locate "A" a second time?

Comment: Yes I'm waiting

Comment: Can you please share the element HTML code before and after you refresh?

Comment: @BryanOakley, I couldn't share HTML code, it is official site and password protected,    I'm getting a Xpath first time, same XPath showing an  element not found ,    but again if I inspect via firepath I'm getting the same XPath, every time after page refresh, DOM elements are not loaded until I interact with firepath

Comment: @A.Kootstra, HTML element added in the main question

Comment: Can you confirm that the button is in fact visible? In the after source code I see that `<div class="aspNetHidden">` suggests strongly that it isn't.

Comment: Yes, Button DOM is not visible after the page refresh, but If I try firepath focuser, It gets visible, how to automate this?